# & is not detected in Query string paramter

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to pass an API from node where the character contains '&' (eg: AT&T), IN url query parameter I am not getting the vales associated with AT&T but its returning empty string. Anyone has idea about it?

http://localhost:3000/Account?accountName=AT&T

[]

Comment: encode the string - `encodeURIComponent("AT&T")`

Comment: `?accountName=AT&T` is a key `accountName` with value `AT` and a key `T` with no value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encode the URL and decode it before getting the query parameters. You can use encodeURIComponent() to encode and decodeURIComponent() to decode.

How to use them check [here1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) and [here2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?